# wordpress shorcode php into html output

Tags: php, wordpress, return, output, shortcode

i have this code:

```
// Add Shortcode Team
function team_code() {
$output = "";
$output .= "<div id='b-team-all'>";
$output .= "<div class='header-team'>";
$output .= "<span class='b-icon'><i class='fa fa-users' aria- hidden='true'></i></span>";
$output .= "<p></p>";
$output .= "<h2>Náš tím</h2>";
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "<div id='b-full-grid'>";
$output .= "<div id='b-team'>";
$output .= "<?php foreach( get_cfc_meta( 'tim' ) as $key => $value ){ ?>";
$output .= "<div class='b-team-member' style='background-image: url('<?php  the_cfc_field( 'tim','fotka', false, $key ); ?>');'>";
$output .= "<div class='b-team-text'>";
$output .= "<h1><?php the_cfc_field( 'tim','meno', false, $key );  ?></h1>";
$output .= "<divider></divider>";
$output .= "<span><?php the_cfc_field( 'tim','postavenie', false, $key ); ?></span>";
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "<div class='b-team-overlay'>";
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "<?php } ?>";
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "</div>";

return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'team', 'team_code' );
```

how, to write right this php? Now getting  php in this way doesnt working, im not very good in this :) can someone help?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's some horrible looking code! :-P But! Here's what you want.

Change for instance:

```
$output .= "<span><?php the_cfc_field( 'tim','postavenie', false, $key ); ?></span>";
```

To this:

```
$output .= "<span>".the_cfc_field( 'tim','postavenie', false, $key )."</span>";
```

For your foreach, do the following. Change:

```
$output .= "<?php foreach( get_cfc_meta( 'tim' ) as $key => $value ){ ?>";
```

To this:

```
foreach( get_cfc_meta( 'tim' ) as $key => $value ){
```

And this line:

```
$output .= "<?php } ?>";
```

To just

`}`

Then it will loop through and you can continue adding to `$output`.

Comment: Hello, thanks and yes, btw, this working, but what about

         foreach( get_cfc_meta( 'tim' ) as $key => $value ){

Comment: i tried this, but, loop show over html, and html stay empty... :/

Answer (score 0):

```
 function team_code(){
<div id='b-team-all'>
<div class='header-team'>
    <span class='b-icon'><i class='fa fa-users' aria- hidden='true'></i></span>
        <p></p>
    <h2>Náš tím</h2>
</div>
<div id='b-full-grid'>
    <div id='b-team'>
        <?php foreach( get_cfc_meta( 'tim' ) as $key => $value ){ ?>
        <div class='b-team-member' style='background-image: url('<?php  the_cfc_field( 'tim','fotka', false, $key ); ?>');'>
            <div class='b-team-text'>
                <h1><?php the_cfc_field( 'tim','meno', false, $key );  ?></h1>
            <divider></divider>
            <span><?php the_cfc_field( 'tim','postavenie', false, $key ); ?></span>
            </div>
                <div class='b-team-overlay'>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
}
 add_shortcode('team','team_code');
```

Why are you concanitating the codes if you find it really hard

Answer (score 0):

Solved i get result, was my bad:

```
// Add Shortcode Team
function team_code() {

$output = "";
$output .= "<div id='b-team-all'>";
$output .= "<div class='header-team'>";
$output .= "<span class='b-icon'><i class='fa fa-users' aria- hidden='true'></i></span>";
$output .= "<p></p>";
$output .= "<h2>Náš tím</h2>";
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "<div id='b-full-grid'>";
$output .= "<div id='b-team'>";
foreach( get_cfc_meta( 'tim' ) as $key => $value ){
    $url_foto = get_cfc_field( 'tim', 'fotka', false, $key );
    $header = get_cfc_field( 'tim','meno', false, $key );
    $position = get_cfc_field( 'tim','postavenie', false, $key );

    $output .= "<div class='b-team-member' style='background-image: url(" . $url_foto['url'] . ")'>";
    $output .= "<div class='b-team-text'>";
    $output .= "<h1>" . $header . "</h1>";
    $output .= "<divider></divider>";
    $output .= "<span>" . $position . "</span>";
    $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "<div class='b-team-overlay'>";
    $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "</div>";
    $output .= "</div>";
}
$output .= "</div>";
$output .= "</div>";

return $output;

}
add_shortcode( 'team', 'team_code' );
```